# What happened to Mundungus Fletcher after the Second Wizarding War

Tags: harry-potter

Mundungus vanished after seeing Voldemort and was last seen in the Order's Hideout.

**Did Rowling mention his whereabouts after the Wizarding War or was he just not an important character?**

Answer (score 5):

There are no further mentions of Mundungus's movements after he's seen at Grimmauld Place within the novels (or films), nor has JKR mentioned him in any of the articles on Pottermore, her original website, any interviews, nor on her twitter account.

Basically he's a minor character with few redeeming qualities that no-one really likes, who exists (within the books) solely to further the plot. It's certainly *possible* that he took part in the Battle of Hogwarts with the rest of the Order of the Phoenix, but it's far more likely that he just skulked off and hid until the fighting was over, then resumed his life of dubious virtue.